# UWP and SQLite: how to manage properly DataTime?

Tags: c#, sqlite, datetime, uwp, localtime

I've developed a **UWP app** that use a **SQLite database** to sync datas.
I've created a ***"Sync_Details"*** object that store the latest **DateTime** of each kind of synchronized data (server's data, form's data, user's data, ...)

When I **save** the object, I've the **"right" values**, corresponding to my local  time:
[image: Save]

But when I relaunch the app, which **restores** these values: all the DateTime have **"lost" one hour**:
[image: Load]

I tried to pass through a **DateTimeOffset** (for ***"dateLastUsersSync"***), but the result is the same: I must convert the value to local time to get the expceted value:

```
dateLastServerSync.Value.ToLocalTime();
```

I also tried to set the parameter ***"storeDateTimeAsTicks"*** to false, but this didn't change anything:

```
var connString = new SQLiteConnectionString(path, storeDateTimeAsTicks: false);
```

***=> Would you have any idea? I must convert each DateTime to local time, which isn't really a good practice... Isn't it possible to force this on the SQLite database?***

Comment: The ordinary NET SQLite db can be set to save and read back everything as UTC.  Not sure it applies here

Comment: But how can we set it? In many cases, developers use the same solution than me: "ToLocalTime()". Isn't it a "proper" way to manage this?

Comment: In the `System.Data.SQLite`  provider there are some relatively new flags, `DateTimeKind` and `BindDateTimeWithKind`: these make the connection a UTC or Local one and all `DateTime` types passed are converted for you.  Look for similarly named settings

Comment: Please provide more details like method for saving data and the data type which you have declared.